# Getting an Unknown CORS error in Odoo-12 POS UI Book Orders

Tags: javascript, json, odoo, odoo-12

I am getting this error on POS UI I really need help because I don't understand the error

I am using the Book Order module and I often get this error like 1 in 10 book orders

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at child.add_product (point_of_sale.assets.js:493)
    at Class.line_select (point_of_sale.assets.js:429)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (point_of_sale.assets.js:425)
    at HTMLTableSectionElement.dispatch (web.assets_common.js:892)
    at HTMLTableSectionElement.elemData.handle (web.assets_common.js:865)
```

here's how I modified the `add_product` function

```
add_product: function(product, options){
            var can_add = true;
            var changes = this.pos.get_order();
            var self = this;
            if(changes.selected_orderline){
                if(changes.selected_orderline.order){
                    if(changes.selected_orderline.order.quotation_ref){
                        if(changes.selected_orderline.order.quotation_ref.book_order){
                            can_add= false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (can_add){
                if(this._printed){
                    this.destroy();
                    return this.pos.get_order().add_product(product, options);
                }
                this.assert_editable();
                options = options || {};
                var attr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(product));
                attr.pos = this.pos;
                attr.order = this;
                var line = new POSInheritmodel.Orderline({}, {pos: this.pos, order: this, product: product});
                if(options.quantity !== undefined){
                    line.set_quantity(options.quantity);
                }

                if(options.price !== undefined){
                    line.set_unit_price(options.price);
                }

                //To substract from the unit price the included taxes mapped by the fiscal position
                this.fix_tax_included_price(line);

                if(options.discount !== undefined){
                    line.set_discount(options.discount);
                }

                if(options.discounted_amount !== undefined){
                    line.set_discount_amount(options.discounted_amount);
                }

                if(options.discount_percentage !== undefined){
                    line.set_if_discount_percentage(options.discount_percentage);
                }

                if(options.discount_amount !== undefined){
                    line.set_if_discount_amount(options.discount_amount);
                }

                if(options.extras !== undefined){
                    for (var prop in options.extras) {
                        line[prop] = options.extras[prop];
                    }
                }

                if(options.uom !== undefined || options.uom !== false){
                    line.set_unit_id(options.uom);  
                }

                if(options.is_board_feet !== undefined && options.is_board_feet){
                    line.set_is_board_feet(true);
                    line.set_length(product.length);
                    line.set_thickness(product.thickness);
                    line.set_width(product.width);
                    // console.log(product.length);
                }else if(options.is_board_feet !== undefined && !options.is_board_feet){
                    line.set_is_board_feet(false);
                }else{
                    if(changes.attributes.client !== null){
                        if(changes.attributes.client.is_wholesale || changes.attributes.client.is_retail){
                            if(product.is_board_feet){
                                line.set_is_board_feet(true);
                                line.set_length(product.length);
                                line.set_thickness(product.thickness);
                                line.set_width(product.width);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(options.is_lineal_feet && options.is_lineal_feet !== undefined){
                    line.set_is_lineal_feet(true);
                    line.set_length(product.length);
                    // console.log(product.length);
                }else if(options.is_lineal_feet !== undefined && !options.is_lineal_feet){
                    line.set_is_lineal_feet(false);
                }else{
                    if(changes.attributes.client !== null){
                        if(changes.attributes.client.is_wholesale || changes.attributes.client.is_retail){
                            if(product.is_lineal_feet){
                                line.set_is_lineal_feet(true);
                                line.set_length(product.length);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(options.is_lineal_meter && options.is_lineal_meter !== undefined){
                    line.set_is_lineal_meter(true);
                    line.set_length(product.length);
                    // console.log(product.length);
                }else if(options.is_lineal_meter !== undefined && !options.is_lineal_meter){
                    line.set_is_lineal_meter(false);
                }else{
                    if(changes.attributes.client !== null){
                        if(changes.attributes.client.is_wholesale || changes.attributes.client.is_retail){
                            if(product.is_lineal_meter){
                                line.set_is_lineal_meter(true);
                                line.set_length(product.length);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(options.with_base_price){
                    line.set_with_base_price(true);
                    if(options.base_price_discount !== undefined){
                        line.set_base_price_discount(options.base_price_discount);
                    }
                    if(options.markup !== undefined){
                        line.set_markup(options.markup);
                    }
                    // console.log(product.length);
                }
                if(options.is_weight !== undefined && options.is_weight){
                    line.set_is_weight(true);
                    line.set_weight_receipt_display(options.base_weight);
                }else if(options.is_weight !== undefined && !options.is_weight){
                    line.set_is_weight(false);
                    if(options.base_weight !== undefined && options.base_weight != 0){
                        line.set_weight_receipt_display(options.base_weight);
                    }else{
                        line.set_weight_receipt_display(product.weight);
                    }
                }else{
                    if(options.base_weight !== undefined && options.base_weight != 0){
                        line.set_weight_receipt_display(options.base_weight);
                    }else{
                        line.set_weight_receipt_display(product.weight);
                    }
                    if(changes.attributes.client !== null){
                        if(changes.attributes.client.is_wholesale || changes.attributes.client.is_retail){
                            if(product.is_weight){
                                line.set_is_weight(true);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                var to_merge_orderline;
                for (var i = 0; i < this.orderlines.length; i++) {
                    if(this.orderlines.at(i).can_be_merged_with(line) && options.merge !== false){
                        to_merge_orderline = this.orderlines.at(i);
                    }
                }
                if (to_merge_orderline){
                    to_merge_orderline.merge(line);
                } else {
                    this.orderlines.add(line);
                }
                this.select_orderline(this.get_last_orderline());

                if(line.has_product_lot){
                    this.display_lot_popup();
                }
            }else{
                self.pos.gui.show_popup('error',{
                    title :_t('Modification Restricted'),
                    body  :_t('Modification is not allowed for booked orders.'),
                });
            }
        },
```

this is all that I can give I didn't try anything to fix this because I don't really know where to start any help is very much appreciated thank you.

Comment: My guess is that `product` passed into `add_product` is `undefined`, and that the error is being raised here:
  `var attr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(product));`
I get the same error running:
  `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(undefined))`

Comment: It is not the JSON Response.I would recommend opening the chrome dev tools, navigating to the Network tab, refreshing the page, and then look for the request in question and see what is actually getting returned from the server.